# How to disable SPDY in Google Chrome

Tags: http, google-chrome, spdy

I'd like to know how to disable automatically using SPDY protocol in Google Chrome.
I need to make some IDS related tests and for that purpose I'd like to temporarily access Twitter or Google using HTTP SSL and not SPDY.

Is there even an option to disable it in Chrome? I couldn't find anything on Google.

Regards!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well, you just need to run `chrome` with SPDY support disabled, that's all! Like this:

`"...\chrome.exe" --use-spdy=off`

Comment: does nothing on my v40 build. this will become the same moving target we had for disabling referrer all over again...

Comment: You need do close all chrome instances before this will work. You can check this by opening this page: chrome://net-internals/#http2

Comment: Can I put it somehow in permanent settings on OSX so that not to add this key every time?

Answer (score 1):

you can check all the setting by going to
chrome://flags/

and disable spdy there and relaunch chrome.

Comment: There isn't a spdy option in the flags panel. My Chrome version is  44.0.2403.107.

Comment: As above, option does not exist in chrome://flags/

Comment: I don't know why people are down-voting you. When you posted it in Jan 2015 it was there and it was removed (along with Async DNS) by Google in mid March 2015.

Answer (score -1):

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome]
"DisableSpdy"=dword:00000001
```

Comment: You should probably provide something more than a registry key incase people don't know what they're looking at there. Also, as it's a registry key, it'll only work on Windows.

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Comment: This registry key may have existed in an earlier version, but does not exist for me. Chrome Version 70.0.3538.110 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score -3):

disable Experimental QUIC protocol.

chrome ver 45.0.2454.93

Comment: Maybe you can write something more for him?

Comment: This is a useless answer

Comment: He means the Experimental QUIC Protocol option in chrome://flags. No idea if this actually disables SPDY though. Really wouldn't have hurt to mention where you find the option.