# Loading resources via URL is slow in Chrome - ONLY via https, ONLY from one specific website

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, slowdown

I have this 1 Mb file for testing purposes (though the issue applies to any file hosted at lptoronto.com): https://lptoronto.com/sandbox/test.png

It always loads instantly in Internet Explorer (both via http and https).

**In Google Chrome** (currently Version 63.0.3239.132 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Windows 10) the situation is as follows.

**When fetched via http**, this file loads instantly without an issue.

**When fetched via https**, the same file takes about 40 (!) seconds to load (with very rare and irregular exceptions, when it also loads fast via https on occasion).

**Chrome network monitor** shows that all that 40 seconds the image is being slowly but steadily downloaded at low speed, i.e. there is nothing like waiting for server response etc.

**Here's the screencast** showing IE and Chrome side-by-side loading the same image:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M4cUuhG1YuM

From time to time the issue disappears for a few minutes or an hour, but then re-appears again, without me doing anything on my side.

Same behavior is observed on at least one other computer - the one of my colleague (different ISP, different location).

Needless to say that I'm testing in a clean environment - cache cleared, extensions, firewall, antivirus disabled, connection verified and measured etc.

No Chrome issue whatsoever with any other website, be it http or https.

**Hosting provider** is yet unable to troubleshoot on their end, but they're still trying to help (it takes some time). They tried disabling mod_deflate, re-installing SSL, disabling caching rules, but to no avail.

The same issue was once observed about 2 months ago. That time I asked the hosting provider to disable SSL completely just to be able to work on my website content. When they re-enabled SSL in less than a day, the issue has gone; but now it re-appeared again, and there is no clue as to what is going on.

The bottomline:

- issue appears only in Chrome, only with certain site, only with https
- changing only the browser solves the issue
- changing only the protocol (https to http) solves the issue

I honestly tried to google out anything similar, but failed to.

**I would appreciate if you try the link above in the incognito Chrome window and report the load/refresh time, and of course any ideas are more than welcome.**

Comment: it sounds like the problem is on the server side. But anyway, there are some checks possible on the browser : see https://www.ghacks.net/2015/03/12/images-slow-down-chrome-to-a-crawl-try-this-fix/ . You also can try launching chrome with --disable-byte-range-support

Comment: try disabling SPDY support too ( --use-spdy=off ), see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12264568/how-to-disable-spdy-in-google-chrome

Comment: Thank you. At present time the issue has gone [again for some time?]. I will follow your advice as soon as it's back.